# Get LD_LIBRARY_PATH value from the postgresql-9.1 service

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, shell, service

Can anyone please suggest me that how can I get the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the postgresql-9.1 service, which is registered as part of PostgreSQL9.1 installaion using shell script.

I need to get the value till `/opt/testing/bin(where pg_dump will available)`

Based on the value I need to take the backup of old DB and reset the DataBase.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: If the service is running, look up the pid of it using `ps` and then read `/proc/<pid>/environ` for the process You were looking for. You should be able to extract the variable from there if it was modified by the script starting PostgreSQL. Otherwise just relying on `env` should do the trick.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow - you want superuser or serverfault. But you also need to explain this properly. You say you want `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but if you're looking for `pg_dump` you just need to set the `PATH` env var, or run `/opt/testing/bin/pg_dump` directly. So this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hi craig, I want to use pg_dump to take a backup of old DB. For that I need the location of pg_dump.That is my intention here.Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If everyone understood my question correctly, this was the answer I was looking for.Finally did it myself as well sharing the answer.

```
    path=`grep -oE "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\S*:" /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.1`
    echo "path:"$path
    path_array=($path)
    ld_lib_path=${path_array[0]}
    echo "ld_lib_path : "$ld_lib_path
    ld_lib_path1=${ld_lib_path#*=}
    ld_lib_path2=${ld_lib_path1%:*}
    echo "ld_lib_path2 : "$ld_lib_path2
    cd $ld_lib_path2
    cd ../bin
```

Now we can use pg_dump,pg_dumpall to take backup of old DataBase.